# Repeater with 2 columns and fixed numbe of rows - how?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a requirement to have fixed number of rows (i.e. 10 rows) in a Repeater, with 2 columns. 
For example, I have a list of 15 items (i.e. Item 1, Item 2, ...Item 16). The repeater must present the data like below:

The first column must be filled up with 10 items before starting to fill the second one.

Please provide suggestions.

**Required Output Format:**

[image: Output format image]

```html
<pre>
    <table>    
        <tr><td>Item 1</td> <td>Item 11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 2</td> <td>Item 12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 3</td> <td>Item 13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 4</td> <td>Item 14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 5</td> <td>Item 15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 6</td> <td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 7</td> <td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 8</td> <td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 9</td> <td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item 10</td> <td></td></tr>
    </table>
</pre>
```

So far, I have this

[image: Please see attached screenshot of the code I currently have]

Suggestions also welcome on how to do this using a DataList or other data controls.

Comment: post the code what you have tried, so that we can modify and rectify rather than we builting from scratch

Comment: Put your screenshot in the code, then we can take a look on that (Copy and Paste and Edit). also show what else you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` to solve it. Here is the solution. If you have events for content then use `clone`.

```js
$(function(){
var maxRows=6,totalRecords = $("table tr").length,requiredColumns =Math.floor(totalRecords/maxRows)+1,emptyCells=(totalRecords%maxRows);
console.log(emptyCells);
var index=0;
$("table tr").eq(maxRows-1).nextAll("tr").each(function(){ 
 if(index==maxRows)
  index=0;
 $("table tr").eq(index).append($(this).html());
 $(this).remove();
 index++;
 
});
$("table tr:nth-child("+ emptyCells+")").nextAll("tr").append("<td></td>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>    
<tr><td>Item 1</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 2</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 3</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 4</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 5</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 6</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 7</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 9</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 10</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 11</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 12</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 13</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 14</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 15</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Item 16</td> </tr>
</table>
```

```
$(function(){
var maxRows=6,totalRecords = $("table tr").length,requiredColumns =Math.floor(totalRecords/maxRows)+1,emptyCells=(totalRecords%maxRows);
console.log(emptyCells);
var index=0;
$("table tr").eq(maxRows-1).nextAll("tr").each(function(){  
    if(index==maxRows)
        index=0;
    $("table tr").eq(index).append($(this).html());
    $(this).remove();
    index++;

});
$("table tr:nth-child("+ emptyCells+")").nextAll("tr").append("<td></td>");
});
```

Comment: This solution is simple and clear - this is why I picked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you give us your current code I can convert it to do it,
In a Plain Console Application you can do the following

```
var items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
int cols = 4;
int rows = 5;
items = Sort(items, cols, rows);

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % cols == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("<tr>");
    Console.WriteLine("   <td>Item {0}</td>", items[i]);

    if ((i + 1) % cols == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("</tr>");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

If you cannot convert it yourself I will help you but this should give an Idea how to do it

EDIT 1:
Here is my blind code to what you have, use it inside of your Repeater

```
((Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0) ? "<tr>" : String.Empty)
    <td>Data</td>
(((Container.ItemIndex + 1) % 2 == 0) ? "</tr>" : String.Empty)
```

EDIT 2:
You will only need to take the Items and sort it before it is Bound to the Repeater. I.E my code wil generate

```
<tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
</tr>
```

and you want

```
<tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
</tr>
```

I will update again the Console one to give an Idea how to sort the data

This method should work to sort it in the right columns, see the console app again

```
    private static T[] Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int cols, int rows)
    {
        var enumerable = items.Take(cols * rows).ToArray();//Prevents the throw of exception, will take only the first items
        var length = enumerable.Length;
        var columLenght = length / cols;
        var itemList = enumerable.ToList();
        var converted = new List<List<T>>();
        //Create columns of existing data
        while (itemList.Count > 0)
        {
            var nextSet = itemList.Take(rows).ToList();
            itemList.RemoveRange(0, nextSet.Count);
            while (nextSet.Count < rows)
            {
                nextSet.Add(default(T));
            }
            converted.Add(nextSet.ToList());
        }
        //Create Empty Columns
        while (converted.Count < cols)
        {
            var emptyColumn = (new T[rows]).ToList();
            converted.Add(emptyColumn);
        }
        //Move into correct columns
        while (converted.Sum(x => x.Count) > 0)
        {
            foreach (var columItems in converted)
            {
                if (columItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    var item = columItems[0];
                    itemList.Add(item);
                    columItems.RemoveRange(0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        if (cols * rows != itemList.Count)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Ratio between new list is smaller to the given list"); //Sanity, this shouldn't happen
        return itemList.ToArray();
    }
```